# 301 Redirect domain Sub-folders to Subdomain subfolder

Tags: htaccess

I have a domain and subdomain `example.com` and `music.example.com` and they are both on root directory `/public_html`

I want to redirect `example.com/music/end/` to `music.example.com/music/end/`but since the both of them are in root directory it is giving me redirection error.

Please is there any way i can make 301 redirection from the old url to the new one without getting errors

Comment: Please share your current directives that are giving you this error. And specifically, what kind error are you getting; a redirect loop?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^ng-music/(.*) https://music.example.com/music/$1 [R=301,L]` that is the htaccess code i tried.

Comment: Curious, that directive doesn't really relate to the desired redirect you stated in the question? You are also _changing_ the URL-path with that directive. In my answer below I've assumed the URL-path is passed through unchanged - as in your example. Is this not the case? Your directive also suggests that `end` is variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both the main domain and subdomain point to the same directory on the filesystem, then you need to check the requested host using a mod_rewrite *condition*.

So, for example, the following directives should go *before* the WordPress front-controller (ie. *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` section):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(music/end/)$ http://music.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The use of backreferences in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* is simply to prevent repetition. `%1` is a backreference to the captured group in the last matched *CondPattern* (ie. `example.com`) and `$1` is a backreference to the captured group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. `music/end/`).

You need to use mod_rewrite (as opposed to a mod_alias `Redirect`) since you most probably have existing mod_rewrite directives associated with WordPress, and there could be conflicts otherwise. Besides, you can't check the `Host` header using mod_alias.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

**UPDATE:** From your comment...

> ```
> RewriteRule ^ng-music/(.*) https://music.example.com/music/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

This does something different to the "desired" redirect as stated in your question. By itself, this shouldn't result in a redirect loop.

Comment: but what if i have more than 12 url to redirects

Comment: Glad you got it working. The browser cache can be a problem when testing 301 (permanent) redirects. As the browser is just as likely to cache the _errors_. It is often recommended to first test with 302 (temporary) redirects - that should not be cached by default - and change to 301 once you have confirmed it works OK.

Comment: You can repeat the above 12 times, or if there is a _pattern_, then you can create the appropriate regex to cover all 12 URLs? There are some other tricks like _skipping_ directives, but it would be preferable to look for a _pattern_ to these 12 URLs.

Comment: LOL, thanks a lot I appreciate your time and effort.